# Need to access Stock Qty on a category view

Tags: magento-2.1, category, blocks, frontend, stock

Using Magento 2.1.7 - Stock fustration

Hi, I need to be able to access on a category view each of the products stock qty.

I need this so I can then display a particular icon against each product dependant on the value.  If 0 show an out of stock icon, else, show an in stock icon which wont be a problem but accessing the stock details from the product collection is baffling me.

Any pointers would be very gratefully received.

Cheers
Jim

Answer (score 0):

`protected $stockItem;`

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockItem
    ) {
        $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

public function getStockQty(ModelProduct $product)
{
    $qty = $this->stockItem->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    return $qty;
}
```

You will have to pass `$product` object to get QTY.

Hope it helps :)